# How to prevent my app from playing sound if device is already playing music

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I am developing an iPhone app that will play its own sounds at the request of the user.

My question is if the device is already playing music, how can I disable the sound within my app on launch?

I know I will have to detect if the device is already playing music, but how can I do that?

Comment: `I know I will have to detect if Sound is already playing` - wrong. Check closer on the documentation for audiosession setup - watch specifically out for "Audio Session Categories".

Comment: Establish the appropriate audio session and that will pause any music that's already playing.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I appreciate your time you given to this question!

Comment: I have used this category AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient but it will allow the iPod sound to be plays while I am using the app but I need to mute the app's sound if iPod is playing the music!

Comment: Kudos for wanting to respect the user's opinion on what sound should be coming out of their device. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either activate an audio session like so:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

or you could create a `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]` instance and pause the music, but this wont pause music being played inside other apps.

**Edit**

If you want to check if the iPod is playing music then you could do something like this:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
if ([musicPlayer playbackState] == == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
   //iPod is playing music, do something here
}
```

You'll need to add the `MediaPlayer` framework.

Answer (score 0):

To check if you are already playing music, you could do something like :

```
(YES == ((AVAudioSession *)[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]).otherAudioPlaying)
```